# Android ExoPlayer controls not working after setting player

Tags: android, service, playback, exoplayer

I have an Android app that plays audio using ExoPlayer running in service. In Activity-A you can select a track to play. The service starts and begins playing the audio. The controls become visible and everything looks normal:

[image]

When I move to Activity-B the audio continues to play in the background since it's a service. When I return back to Activity-A the controls appear but are not displaying correctly. The audio is still playing fine but the progress bar is not right and both the play and pause button are showing instead of just pause:

[image]

I have to interact with the controls, like click the play button, and then they look normal again with the progress bar showing correctly.

This is the method that attaches the player to the controls:

```
private void initializePlayer() {
    if (isBound && audioPlayerService != null) {
        player = audioPlayerService.getPlayerInstance();
        playerControlView.setPlayer(player);
    }
}
```

Why don't the controls work straight away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed with the following code:

```
private void initializePlayer() {
    if (isBound && audioPlayerService != null) {
        player = audioPlayerService.getPlayerInstance();
        if (audioPlayerService.isPlaying()) {
            playerControlView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        playerControlView.setPlayer(player);
    }

}
```

Explanation:

After some research, I noticed that after you attach your player to your view using `PlayerControlView.setPlayer()`, the `PlayerControlView.updateAll()` method is called to get everything looking right. However, there is a check to see if the controls are visible and the updates don't get done (the method exits) unless the controls are actually visible:

```
if (!isVisible() || !isAttachedToWindow) {
  return;
}
```

In my code, I was attaching the player to the controls first before making them visible (which seemed logical to me) so that was the issue.

Comment: In my code its working for video but when i use it for audio controllers are visible but doesn't work. My code is like :

Comment: private var audioPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
audioPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context of the activity, DefaultTrackSelector())
audio_player_view.player = audioPlayer
audio_player_view.controllerShowTimeoutMs = 0
audio_player_view.useController =true
val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context of the activity, getString(R.string.app_name)))
val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(filePath));  audioPlayer!!.prepare(mediaSource);
audioPlayer!!.playWhenReady = true

Comment: <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
 android:id="@+id/audio_player_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:use_controller="true">
 </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>